# How to bundle javascript classes and modules together using webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to bundle my all classes and modules using webpack, but facing some issues. I tried many solutions, but failed.
I have following module which is an entry point for webpack, I am importing other modules and classes inside this module.

**MyModule.js**

```
import {utilities} from "./Utilities.js";   //which is a module
import myClass from "./MyClass.js";   //which is a class
import myObject from "./MyObject.js";   //which is a javascript object

var myModule = (function(){

    function myFunc(){ ...}

    return {
        myFunc:myFunc
    };
})();
```

**Utilities.js**

```
export var utilities = (function(){
   //code lines
})();
```

**MyClass.js**

```
export class myClass {
   //code lines
}
```

**MyObject.js**

```
export var myObject = {
   prop1:"xyz",
   prop2:"pqr"

}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
entry: './MyModule.js',
    output: {
      path: './dist',
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      libraryTarget: 'var',
      library: 'MyModule'
    }
};
```

These are all my JS files. And I am calling `myModule.myFunc()` on click of button in *Test.html*

**Test.html**

```
<script src="dist/bundle.js">
<button onclick="myModule.myFunc()">Test</button>
```

After clicking the button I am getting an error,
*typeError: myModule.myFunc is not a function.*

Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Most likely a simple typo: You define your library as `MyModule` in webpack, but call it as `myModule`.

Comment: Typically, the "dist" folder is used as the root of your app after running it through webpack. You are referencing "<script src="dist/bundle.js">" in your html. Is this correct ?

Comment: Can you show us what the transpiled result (`/dist/bundle.js`) looks like?

Comment: "*`export var utilities = (function(){
   //code lines
})();`*" is weird. Why are you using an IIFE when you already have a module?

Comment: Your imports of `MyClass.js` and `MyObject.js` don't match their exports. You are using a default import but a single named export. Did you mean `default export class myClass {…}` and `default export {
   prop1:"xyz",
   prop2:"pqr"
}`?

Comment: @hindmost Yeah, did correction. Still error exist

Comment: @PaW Yeah I think its correct.